# react-native Hermes build show error messag, warning: the variable "URLSearchParams"?

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

```
 "react-native": "0.61.5",
```

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true, 
]
```

run `.\gradlew assembleRelease`:

```
warning: The first definition was here.

android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle:135:2107: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in function " 440#"
__d(function(g,r,i,a,m,e,d){var t,o;t=this,o=function(t){'use strict';var o={searchParams:'URLSearchParams'in self,iterable:'Symbol'in self&&'iterator'in Symbol,blob:'FileReader'in self&&'Blob'in self&&(function(){try{return new
```

set `enableHermes: false,`, Can work, No error message

but set `enableHermes: true,` Can build, Display the above error message

Answer (score 1):

check **URLSearchParams** variable on you whole project some where it was not declare.Because hermes is not allow this type things like variable is not declare, duplicate variable declare, duplicate css propery set in style.You need to fix all this type error manually after that it will work fine.